# How to create random point in according polygon for each dataset entry

Tags: r, spatial

I have a polygon layer (Poly.buffer) that I created, and a dummy dataset of observations (df) which has a common field (i.e., SiteName) with this polygon layer.

I now would like to generate a random point for each dataset entry within the according polygon.

The goal is to have 138 random points, which reside in the according polygon and have all attributes of the datalist.

Here is what I have tried (based on this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74250/how-to-create-random-point-in-according-polygon-for-each-dataset-entry-in-a-list):

```
##load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

##First create dummy dataset
SiteName=c("Site 1", "Site 2", "Site 3", "Site 4", "Site 5")
Latitude=c("-16.40407","-16.41253","-16.39207","-16.40035","-16.40457")
Longitude=c("145.8157","145.7117","145.8308","145.8368","145.8405")

Poly=data.frame(SiteName,Latitude, Longitude)
Poly$Latitude=as.numeric(as.character(Poly$Latitude))
Poly$Longitude=as.numeric(as.character(Poly$Longitude))

Site1=data.frame(SiteName="Site 1",value=1:10)
Site2=data.frame(SiteName="Site 2",value=1:3)
Site3=data.frame(SiteName="Site 3",value=1:64)
Site4=data.frame(SiteName="Site 4",value=1:13)
Site5=data.frame(SiteName="Site 5",value=1:18)
Site1x=data.frame(SiteName="Site 1",value=1:30)
df=dplyr::bind_rows(Site1,Site2,Site3,Site4,Site5,Site1x)

##Create Poly.buffer##
coordinates(Poly)=~Longitude+Latitude
proj4string(Poly)=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
Poly.utm <- spTransform(Poly, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +units=m 
+ellps=WGS84"))
Poly.buffer=gBuffer(Poly.utm,width=400,byid=TRUE)
Poly.buffer=spTransform(Poly.buffer, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

### Preparing the SpatialPointsDataFrame
spdf <- matrix(as.numeric(NA), nlevels(Poly.buffer$SiteName), 1)
spdf <- as.list(spdf)

### Sample the coordinate, match it with data in spdf.
### sample(spsample()) fix the size of the sample
for (i in seq(Poly.buffer$SiteName))
spdf[i] <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(
           sample(spsample(Poly.buffer[order(Poly.buffer$SiteName)==i,], n = 200, "random"),
table(df$SiteName)[[i]]),
           df[df$SiteName==dimnames(table(df$SiteName))[[1]][i],],
           proj4string=poly.crs, 
           match.ID=FALSE)

## Merging together the list to make on SpatialDataFrame
do.call("rbind", spdf) -> spdf
```

The only way that I can run this code, is by selecting match.ID as FALSE. But doing this generates coordinates for each data set entry that do not match the according polygon.

See below what it looks like when I plot it:

```
df.spdf=as.data.frame(spdf)
fPoly.buffer=fortify(Poly.buffer)
ggplot(data=df.spdf, aes(x=x,y=y)) +  geom_polygon(data=fPoly.buffer, 
aes(long, lat, group = group)) + geom_point(size=0.1,aes(color=SiteName))
```

[image]

When I try to run the code with match.ID=TRUE, I get the follwoing error message:

> Error in
>   SpatialPointsDataFrame(sample(spsample(Poly[order(Poly$SiteName) ==  :
>   row.names of data and coords do not match

I am not sure how to progress with this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

See below, what it is supposed to look like. The code works fine when I exclude Site1x from the dummy df. But I need it to work with it.

[image]

Comment: I recommend creating a small/minimal example data set to include in your question so others can recreate your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, I now created an example dataset to better illustrate my question.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that when I executed the do.call function, it merged the different list components based on the row number. I fixed this by simply reordering my dataset, and reassigning new row numbers.

```
df=df[order(df$SiteName),]
rownames(df) <- 1:nrow(df)
```